# Load iframe only when needed

Tags: javascript, html

I have the below where `trigger open` is a sliding div that exposes the `cnt` class housing the iframe.  I want the iframe to only load when the trigger is activated exposing the iframe.

How do I load the iframe only when clicked vs as the page loads?

```
    <div class="trigger open"><a href="#">Search The Map</a></div>

<!-- Hidden until Trigger class is clicked -->
    <div class="cnt">
        <iframe width="500" height="500" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="http://externalpage.com/"></iframe>
    </div>
```

Comment: Did you try to set the iframe src property to empty and then set it with value using javascript when the link is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be on [this way](http://jsfiddle.net/Na6HT/2/)?

Also you would try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4fzaR/).

Answer (score 0):

You can either set the iframe's src to something like "`about:blank`" to prevent it from loading anything (should work in most modern browsers) but the better idea would be to just innerHTML the whole iframe when it's actually needed. Then show / hiding `<div class="cnt">` after that.